# Gradle naming conventions: when to use 'myProj' and when ':myProj'?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to understand the naming conventions in gradle and the impact on semantics and functionality.

I've seen examples like:

```
import 'myProj'
project(':myProj').projectDir = new File(...)
```

and others like:

```
import ':myProj'
project(':myProj').projectDir = new File(...)
```

What does the prefix `:` mean and when do I have to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that without `:` you a *name*, whereas with `:`, a path is used. The same applies to tasks, so please have a look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10C50).

When you refer to projects/tasks on the first level there's no difference if you use `:` or not. But if you need to invoke - from root of the project - a task that is defined several levels lower you need to provide the full path. That's all.